# Can't use user variable in Selecting

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't use user-defined variables in selecting with condition. This one works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM cities 
WHERE province = 'CA' AND state = 'LA'
```

But this one don't:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM cities 
WHERE province =@province:= 'CA' AND state =@state:= 'LA'
```

when I use second query I get a lot of errors and it says:

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'CA' 
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'CA'.
```

I don't know how to fix it? any idea?

Comment: What are you even trying to do? you are adding a variable and setting it up in the query itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed parentheses:

```
WHERE province = (@province:= 'CA') AND state = (@state:= 'LA')
```

(However, James's answer is 'better'.)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for it.

Answer (score 3):

This question seems to be a vague but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT @province:= 'CA', @state:= 'LA';
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM cities WHERE province = @province AND state = @state;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try set the vars properly  before the select

```
  SET @province= 'CA';
  SET @state= 'LA';
  SELECT DISTINCT city 
  FROM cities 
  WHERE province =@province 
  AND state =@state;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this -- set the variables as you do the select statement?

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, @province = province, @state = state 
FROM cities 
WHERE province = 'CA' AND state = 'LA'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use user defined variables in a `select` first `set` then use it.

**Method #1**

```
SET @province = 'CA';
SET @state    = 'LA';

SELECT DISTINCT
    city
FROM
    cities
WHERE
    province = @province AND state = @state;
```

**Method #2** 
If need in a single query then

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM cities
JOIN (SELECT @province := 'CA', @state := 'LA') init
WHERE
    province = @province AND state = @state;
```